# Crash when i click menu icon with slidingmenu

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-menu, slidingmenu

Using the library slidingmenu and actionbarsherlock i try to write the code to make clickable the icon in the actionbar but i get an error with crash. This is the code of toggle:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        menu.toggle();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The logcat says:

```
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at com.db.batt.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:512)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onMenuItemSelected(Watson.java:118)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlock.java:604)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:92)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:204)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:171)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4247)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17733)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:743)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559)
10-01 15:18:00.134: E/AndroidRuntime(27038):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can i solve?

EDIT:
The slidingmenu in my onCreate

```
SlidingMenu menu;
        menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidth(50);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.30f);
        menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setBehindWidth(420);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

so `menu` is declared not?

Comment: I can only guess that menu is null. You need to double click `at com.db.batt.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:512)` in your logcat to know exactly which line has the error

Comment: put entire MainActivity.java

Comment: take a look at the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is that you haven't initialized `menu` variable, and this line.-

```
 menu.toggle();
```

throws the `NullPointerException`.

**EDIT**

You're declaring a local variable `menu` in `onCreate`, but trying to access to an instance variable in `onOptionsItemSelected`. Remove the line.-

```
SlidingMenu menu;
```

Comment: i put the slidingmenu in onCreate

Comment: Please, post relevant code. You may be redeclaring the menu variable local to `onCreate`, but not initializing the instance variable.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're actually doing what I though. I edited my answer.

Comment: Glad it worked :) If the answer was useful, please, consider upvoting/accepting it, as it'll be helpful for other users too.